# Convert ndc coordinates to world coordinates in fragment shader threejs

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

My goal is to draw a circle around my mouse cursor over a plane.

I get NDC coordinates (-1 to +1) that represent my cursor position:

```
const rect = targetHTML.getBoundingClientRect();
const mousePositionX = event.clientX - rect.left;
const mousePositionY = event.clientY - rect.top;

this._currentPoint = {
  x: (mousePositionX / targetHTML.clientWidth *  2 - 1),
  y: (mousePositionY / targetHTML.clientHeight *  -2 + 1),
};
```

I pass it to my fragment shader via uniforms:

```
this._cursorMaterial.uniforms.uBrushPosition.value =
  new window.THREE.Vector2(this._currentPoint.x, this._currentPoint.y);
```

In my fragment shader, I want to convert it to a world coordinate in order to compare it to the fragment world location.

```
// vertex shader
varying vec4 vPos;
void main() {
  vPos = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
}

// fragment shader
varying vec4 vPos;
uniform vec2 uBrushPosition;
void main() {
  // convert uBrush position to world space
  // uBrushPosition
  vec3 brushWorldPosition = ?

  // 
  if (distance(brushWorldPosition, vpos) < 10.) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., .5);
  }
  discard;
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to use `THREE.Raycaster()` to find the point of intersection with yout plane and pass its coordinates to the shader, preliminary using `plane.worldToLocal(point_of_intersection)`?

Comment: Ideally not, that is the backup plan  :)

Comment: Could you provide a live code example then? )

Answer (score 0):

Not in the shader, but you can send it in as a uniform.

```
var mouseWorld = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, distanceFromCamera )
mouseWorld.unproject( camera )
```